# Big Swift class results in slow autocomplete inside Xcode - How to split into several files

Tags: xcode, swift

My Swift Xcode project has as main class a `NSViewController` subclass (thereafter the "main controller") which grew to be about 4k lines tall. Most of the logic tied to the main window and main actions of the app are inside this file, as methods of the class.

This results in Xcode being super slow when it comes to autocompletion and typing in general. I want to split the logic into several smaller files which will hopefully speed up my workflow. How can I proceed to do this?

If I have to be more specific, I would guess that what I want to achieve is: moving methods from this main controller to a separate file/class, and then call from the main controller any of these methods that I moved (ideally, this function in a separate file would be able to call other methods inside the main controller as well).

Are `extension`s something that could help in this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've essentially answered your own question with the extension's that don't require the use of inheritance or subclasses.

With `extension`s you can move code to other files and still access everything is your original `ViewController` class as if it was within the same file.

Example:

```
class viewController : NSViewController {


}

// new file
extension viewController {

}
```

Comment: I didn't know we could use extensions without a protocol or inheritance, thanks!

Comment: Do I need to import Cocoa or Foundation in all extension files?

Comment: Yeah you will, only Foundation unless you're using UI components in that file as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a new controller class and I would set it as a parent of your controller.

In this way you can move your methods  to the new the parent controller without changing the logic of you app.

Comment: My general rule for inheritance is: "Don't do it unless you have to" (UIButton, UIViewController, NSDictionary, etc) The OP can achieve what they're after by just extending their main class, or splitting up functionality into more classes, structs, protocols, etc. Using subclasses when you don't HAVE to introduces unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: Also if you split the functionalities using more class you introduce more dependencies. The optimal solution I think, without seeing the code, is to leave all the code in the controller. But as described in the question XCode gets slow, so the source of the problem is not a wrong OP pattern used by the user but Xocde. My suggested solution has the advantage the callers of the method of this controller do not change. Instead if you group some method in new classes you have to change the callers too...and I don't know how big is the project (only the main controller i 4k row..)

Comment: Splitting out code into smaller chunks makes it so much more reusable. Perhaps "tightly coupled" is more in line with what I was talking about. In my opinion, if your classes are larger than 500 lines, you need to do some refactoring.

Comment: There is probably a few methods that I could move into my custom classes already in place but a lot of the code is just convenient to have into the view controller since, when everything is in the same class, they all have access to the same state without me needing to pass a reference to the view controller for example.